# Cannot convert value of type 'SCNMatrix4' to expected argument type 'matrix_float4x4' (aka 'simd_float4x4')

Tags: swift, scenekit, ios11, xcode9-beta, arkit

I got this error while using iOS 11 ARKit(Scenekit - Xcode 9 beta) when i try to set the simdPosition of virtual object. I need to know if it is possible to convert **SCNMatrix4** to **matrix_float4x4** in swift. If so how to convert it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With iOS SDK 11, you can use initializers to convert between `SCNMatrix4` and `simd_float4x4`.

```
import SceneKit

var mat4 = SCNMatrix4()

let f4x4 = simd_float4x4(mat4)

mat4 = SCNMatrix4(f4x4)
```

Comment: How to do the conversion in Objective-C?

Comment: @Hecot, start your own thread, or better start moving your project into Swift.

Comment: Thanks for the great support!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `SCNMatrix4ToMat4`:

```
let matrix = SCNMatrix4()               // matrix is SCNMatrix4
let float4x4 = SCNMatrix4ToMat4(matrix) // float4x4 is matrix_float4x4
```

And if you want to convert `SCNMatrix4` to `matrix_float4x4`, use `SCNMatrix4FromMat4`:

```
let matrix1 = SCNMatrix4FromMat4(float4x4) // matrix1 is SCNMatrix4
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C has the same method:

```
[self.sceneView.session setWorldOrigin:SCNMatrix4ToMat4(node.pivot)];
```